# Simplify makes Mathematica forget that a matrix is Hermitian

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, assumptions

Using `Simplify` with certain trivial assumptions makes Mathematica forget that a given matrix is Hermitian. See the minimal example below:

```
expr = Exp[I*2*π*Re[n]]
mat = {{Re[n], a*expr}, {Conjugate[a]*Conjugate[expr], Re[n]}}
HermitianMatrixQ[mat]
simplifiedmat = Assuming[n ∈ Integers, Simplify[mat]]
HermitianMatrixQ[simplifiedmat]
```

Here I create a Hermitian matrix `mat` with some integer variable `n`. 
Mathematica correctly asserts that `mat` is Hermitian. After this I simplify the matrix under the assumption that `n` is an integer. This nicely removes the exponential expression in the matrix, as expected. However, according to Mathematica this simplified matrix `simplifiedmat` is no longer Hermitian.

This is clearly wrong. Thus I ask if there is any other way to simplify `mat` and maintaining that `simplifiedmat` is Hermitian?

Answer (score 9):

There are two issues here.  The first is that `HermitianMatrixQ` (in line with other `Q` functions) only applies **quick** checks that the matrix is Hermitian.  It is acceptable for it to fail to recognise a matrix as Hermitian, but it must not say that a matrix is Hermitian when it is not.

Secondly, when you apply the test, your assumption for `n` is no longer active.   `HermitianMatrixQ` has to assume it is complex.

Note further (I think) in general `Q` functions do not take account of assumptions.  We have

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers, HermitianMatrixQ[simplifiedmat]]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Ok, I was somewhat hoping that Mathematica was keeping track of assumptions internally. Now I am aware that `Simplify` uses and then discards assumptions, so I need to carry them along by myself.

Answer (score 6):

```
expr = Exp[I*2*π*Re[n]];
mat = {{Re[n], a*expr}, {Conjugate[a]*Conjugate[expr], Re[n]}};
HermitianMatrixQ[mat]

(* True *)

simplifiedmat = Assuming[n ∈ Integers, Simplify[mat]];
```

Use the [`SameTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameTest.html) option to [`HermitianMatrixQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermitianMatrixQ.html) to make use of [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

```
HermitianMatrixQ[simplifiedmat, 
 SameTest -> (Simplify[#1 - #2 == 0, Element[n, Integers]] &)]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a way to use assumptions with functions which do not make use of assumptions themselves. I will keep this in mind for future applications, for now I found a different solution.

Answer (score 4):

The essential problem is that `simplifiedmat` is

```
{{n, a}, {Conjugate[a], n}}
```

Note that this expression contains no hint about the nature of `n`. You told `Simplify` that `n` was an integer, so it naturally simplified `Re[n]` to `n`. One way to fix this is to restore the `Re` after simplifying:

```
HermitianMatrixQ[simplifiedmat /. n -> Re[n]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: This does work rather well, but it requires me to restore all assumptions such as `Re` after every time I do `Simplify`, so I guess in larger projects there is quite some risk to miss one and get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

From the answers above I learned that, unlike sympy, Mathematica does not keep track of assumptions and some functions simply ignore assumptions even if given explicitly.

Thus I thought some more about how to make a symbol `n∈ℝ` in the first place and that's surprisingly simple. Just define `n` as the real part of some new and otherwise unused symbol `nComplex`: `n = Re[nComplex]`. The whole code then becomes

```
n = Re[nComplex]
expr = Exp[I*2*π*Re[n]]
mat = {{Re[n], a*expr}, {Conjugate[a]*Conjugate[expr], Re[n]}}
HermitianMatrixQ[mat]
simplifiedmat = Assuming[n ∈ Integers, Simplify[mat]]
HermitianMatrixQ[simplifiedmat]
```

I have to admit that outputting matrices `mat` and `simplifiedmat` now looks rather ugly, but it does the job without me having to keep track of and reinserting all assumptions after every time I run `Simplify`.